# css layout footer after screen height

Tags: html, css, flexbox

[image]

I want to achieve something like this in CSS.

- Header part should only take the required height for it.
- Content part should fill the rest of the space. (This should be stretch to the bottom of the screen size)
- Footer should start after the height of the screen size. (If someone needs to see the footer he has to scroll

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>Document</title>
    <style>
        body {
         margin: 0;
         padding: 0;
        }
      header {
        height: 5rem;
        padding: 2rem;
        background-color: cornflowerblue;
      }
      footer {
        background-color: crimson;
      }
      .wrapper {
          display: flex;
          height: 100vh;
          flex-direction: column;
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="wrapper">
      <header>
        <h1>Header</h1>
      </header>
      <div style="background-color: darkgreen">Content goes here.</div>
    </div>
    <footer>
      <h1>Footer</h1>
    </footer>
  </body>
</html>
```

This is what I have done. content section (green color) should fill up to the end of the 100vh.

How do I fix this?
Any help!
Thanks in advance. =)

Comment: add ```height:100%;```  like ```<div style="background-color: darkgreen; height:100%;">Content goes here.</div>```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just add `flex-grow: 1` to the `div` with content :)

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>Document</title>
    <style>
        body {
         margin: 0;
         padding: 0;
        }
      header {
        height: 5rem;
        padding: 2rem;
        background-color: cornflowerblue;
      }
      footer {
        background-color: crimson;
      }
      .wrapper {
          display: flex;
          height: 100vh;
          flex-direction: column;
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="wrapper">
      <header>
        <h1>Header</h1>
      </header>
      <div style="background-color: darkgreen; flex-grow: 1;">Content goes here.</div>
    </div>
    <footer>
      <h1 style="margin: 0;">Footer</h1>
    </footer>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use `flex: 1 1 auto` to get the content to take up remaining space. For example

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>Document</title>
    <style>
        body {
         margin: 0;
         padding: 0;
        }
      header {
        height: 5rem;
        padding: 2rem;
        background-color: cornflowerblue;
      }
      footer {
        background-color: crimson;
      }
      .wrapper {
          display: flex;
          height: 100vh;
          flex-direction: column;
      }
      .content {
          background-color: darkgreen;
          flex: 1 1 auto;
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="wrapper">
      <header>
        <h1>Header</h1>
      </header>
      <div class="content">Content goes here.</div>
    </div>
    <footer>
      <h1>Footer</h1>
    </footer>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: really Good solution

Answer (score 1):

You can set HTML and body height as 100% so the div.main can receive percentage values for its height. This must solve your problem.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>Document</title>
    <style>
      html, body{
         height: 100%;
      }
      * {
          margin: 0;
          border: 0;
          box-sizing: border-box;
      }
      header {
        height: 5rem;
        padding: 2rem;
        background-color: cornflowerblue;
      }
      footer {
        background-color: crimson;
      }
      .main{
          height: 100%;
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    
      <header>
        <h1>Header</h1>
      </header>
      <div class="main" style="background-color: darkgreen">Content goes here.</div>
    
    <footer>
      <h1>Footer</h1>
    </footer>
  </body>
</html>
```